# Steam (dota 2) Api problems

Tags: api, url, steam

im trying to get json result of this url

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/v1/?key=*********************************&account_id=76561198059396544
```

and it's complety empty "{ }". I don't know if the api isn't work or my apikey is wrong but i tried with another and it is the same. I tried with another game id but neither work.

Guys can you help?

Comment: Hi, just out of curiosity, what happens when you go to that URL in a web browser? I get a _**forbidden**_ error.

Comment: `https://gyazo.com/7eabd190ca9a26174687311af999d69c`